# Unresolved reference: android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

[image]

As you can see from the image, Android studio is not able to resolve this import "com.android" in this line.

```
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
```

I tried the following truobleshooting found from some other answers:

1. Clean and rebuild
2. File -> invalidate caches and restart
3. Opening the project by build.gradle
4. Deleting the .idea folder in the project
5. Installing old sdk (Android 6.0) along with latest

But none seem to be helping. Help please.

build.gradle (module) file :
https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/326r

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

}
```

Comment: Add module level `build.gradle` file

Comment: Added the module build.gradle file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I thought you forgot to add dependency in your gradle file. Add dependency to module level `build.gradle` file

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete the build folder then resynchronize. Sometimes even using `./gradlew clean` command, the generated file not deleted correctly

Comment: Tried both. Still the same

Comment: Is it just happen to volley lib ? if true then did you already add the volley lib to your Gradle ?

Comment: as i see on your gradle file, you have not add the volley lib.

Comment: Good, glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

It sounds stupid, but in my case, I had `build.gradle` and `build.gradle.kts` files at the same time in the `:app` module folder.

After deleting `build.grale` file it worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes for any reason, the following line appears among the imports

```
import android.R
```

This caused (at least in my case) the error `Unresolved reference: android`.

After removing this line, the error disappears.